# Database query logic issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

I have a database and I'm extracting the following fields:

BookDate -- AirlineCode -- BkngVal

The thing I want to do is to save the output into a json file in the following format:

```
[{
Date: 2016-01-03,
Airline Code: BA,
Airline BkngVal: 1234.00,
Airline Code: VS,
Airline BkngVal: 123.00,
Airline Code: EK,
Airline BkngVal: 8743.09
},
{
Date: 2016-01-04
Airline Code: UA,
Airline BkngVal: 134.00,
Airline Code: BA,
Airline BkngVal: 129.00,
Airline Code: 9W,
Airline BkngVal: 823.09
}]
```

and so on for each date that there is in the database. The problem is that there are multiple bookings made for each airline on the same day so I'm trying to get my head around the best way to group the dates then add the booking val into each airline where it is using that date and then add that into a json file where the date is the main key.

The initial MySql query is:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT BookDate, BkngVal, Market, AirlineCode 
                      FROM sales 
                      WHERE (Market = :market) 
                        AND (BookDate >= :startDate) 
                        AND (BookDate <= :endDate) 
                      ORDER BY BookDate ASC');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        'market' => $location,
        'startDate' => $start,
        'endDate' => $end
    ));
```

Market is the country I want to look at so lets assume it is the UK. So I'm looking at all flights booked in the UK.

How can I loop through these and add the val to the airline and then add it to the json file.

```
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        if ($row['BookDate'] == $BookDate) {

            $airline_sales_made_per_day += $row['BkngVal'];
        }
        else {
            if ($count > 0) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'date' => $BookDate,
                    'airline sales made per day' => $airline_sales_made_per_day
                );
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
```

I know this wont work as all it does is create multiple dates with multiple airline bookings and values so basically making the query into an array.

I just cant think how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'll admit I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to json but that doesn't look like well-formatted json to me.

Comment: order it by the Airline code as the second field in the ORDER BY clause. Then within your db rows loop keep adding to the total until the current row's airline code is different to the previous one. At that point write it to the array and then repeat the process until you get to the next date.

Comment: @strawberry - yeah that is badly formatted but it was just an example of what i wanted.

Comment: @ADyson I will give that a try, thank you.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you that worked

Comment: @Andrew if I add as answer would you please accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order it by the Airline code as the second field in the ORDER BY clause. Then within your db rows loop keep adding to the total until the current row's airline code is different to the previous one. At that point write it to the array and then repeat the process until you get to the next date.